# Too deeply nested

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize, enumitem

I am trying to typeset a large number of exercises, importing all of these exercises (about five hundred) into one master file. While compiling I get the error : `! LaTeX Error: Too deeply nested.` The error is associated with some exercises that have imbriq questions like (itemize in the third level) :

```
\ben 
  \item
  \ben
  \item ...
    \bit 
    \item ...
    \eit
  \item ...
  \een
\item ...
\een
```

where `\bit\eit\ben\een` are defined below (part of my `.cls` file).

```
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep,
         leftmargin = *}
%
\setlistdepth{9}
%
\newlist{myEnumerate}{enumerate}{9}
\setlist[myEnumerate]{
    font        = {\bfseries} ,
    topsep      = 0pt }
\setlist[myEnumerate,1]{label=\arabic* ---,ref=\arabic*}
\setlist[myEnumerate,2]{label=\arabic{myEnumeratei}.\arabic*),ref=\themyEnumeratei.\arabic*}
\setlist[myEnumerate,3]{label=\roman*),ref=\themyEnumerateii.\roman*}
\setlist[myEnumerate,4]{label=\Roman*.,ref=\themyEnumerateiii.\Roman*}
\setlist[myEnumerate,5]{label=\themyEnumerateiiii.\roman*.,ref = \themyEnumerateiiii.\roman*}
\setlist[myEnumerate,6]{label=(\arabic*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,7]{label=(\Roman*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,8]{label=(\Alph*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,9]{label=(\roman*)}
\newcommand{\ben}{\begin{myEnumerate}}
\newcommand{\een}{\end{myEnumerate}}
%
\newlist{myItemize}{itemize}{9}
\setlist[myItemize]{
    topsep      = 0pt }
\setlist[myItemize,1]{label=\faCaretRight}
\setlist[myItemize,2]{label=---}
\setlist[myItemize,3]{label=---}
\setlist[myItemize,4]{label=---}
\setlist[myItemize,5]{label=---}
\setlist[myItemize,6]{label=---}
\setlist[myItemize,7]{label=---}
\setlist[myItemize,8]{label=---}
\setlist[myItemize,9]{label=---}
\newcommand{\bit}{\begin{myItemize}}
\newcommand{\eit}{\end{myItemize}}
```

Oddly, if I try to typeset just one of the suspected exercise (other importations are commented), everything goes well ! Do you see a problem with my `itemize` and `enumerate` declaration? I'm afraid but I'm not able to produce a MWE except by transmitting the whole bank of exercises.

Comment: the error is not due to the number of items but because you have them nested more than 4 deep, it would be possible to extend that but it is not clear if you intend to have that deep a nesting, or if it is due to an error. You should be able to make a small example that shows the problem (you only need a to show a list with one item, one sub-item, one sub-sub-item, nested 4 deep

Comment: you have provided no test file but possibly the `enumitem` package `\setlistdepth{9}` is enough

Comment: Unfortunately the exercise with 4 levels compiles very well on its own. It also seems surprising to me that this only happens in a large file.

Comment: then most likely you have a missing end list or two earlier on the document so nesting deeper than you intend

Comment: I would always advise against doing `\newcommand{\ben}{\begin{myEnumerate}}` it is better to use `\begin` and `\end` explicitly. For some environments (`tabularx`, `align`, ... the short form does not work at all and even when it works it makes it harder for editors and syntax highlighters to correctly match begin and end environments, which is almost surely the issue here.

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine that your document has this form

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep,
         leftmargin = *}
%
\setlistdepth{9}
%
\newlist{myEnumerate}{enumerate}{9}
\setlist[myEnumerate]{
    font        = {\bfseries} ,
    topsep      = 0pt }
\setlist[myEnumerate,1]{label=\arabic* ---,ref=\arabic*}
\setlist[myEnumerate,2]{label=\arabic{myEnumeratei}.\arabic*),ref=\themyEnumeratei.\arabic*}
\setlist[myEnumerate,3]{label=\roman*),ref=\themyEnumerateii.\roman*}
\setlist[myEnumerate,4]{label=\Roman*.,ref=\themyEnumerateiii.\Roman*}
\setlist[myEnumerate,5]{label=\themyEnumerateiiii.\roman*.,ref = \themyEnumerateiiii.\roman*}
\setlist[myEnumerate,6]{label=(\arabic*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,7]{label=(\Roman*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,8]{label=(\Alph*)}
\setlist[myEnumerate,9]{label=(\roman*)}
\newcommand{\ben}{\begin{myEnumerate}}
\newcommand{\een}{\end{myEnumerate}}
%
\newlist{myItemize}{itemize}{9}
\setlist[myItemize]{
    topsep      = 0pt }
\setlist[myItemize,1]{label=\textbullet}
\setlist[myItemize,2]{label=---}
\setlist[myItemize,3]{label=---}
\setlist[myItemize,4]{label=---}
\setlist[myItemize,5]{label=---}
\setlist[myItemize,6]{label=---}
\setlist[myItemize,7]{label=---}
\setlist[myItemize,8]{label=---}
\setlist[myItemize,9]{label=---}
\newcommand{\bit}{\begin{myItemize}}
\newcommand{\eit}{\end{myItemize}}
\begin{document}

\section{The bit you didn't show}

\bit\item\bit\item\bit\item\bit\item
\bit\item\bit\item\bit\item\bit\item

\section{The bit you showed}
\ben 
  \item
  \ben
  \item ...
    \bit 
    \item ...
    \eit
  \item ...
  \een
\item ...
\een

\end{document}
```

which produces the error message

```
! LaTeX Error: Too deeply nested.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.54     \item
               ...
?
```

Which would explain why it only occurs in long documents, you have some construct starting an environment but not closing it so if you get enough of these they force the list nesting to be too deep.

Note that if you do not obscure the environment syntax, and use `\begin` and `\end` explicitly, most editors would be able to  check matching begin end forms.